# Read selection from TableView in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to get the selection from a TableView in JavaFX 2.0.
what happens is that I need to get the value of the row you selected in tableview I hope someone can help me

As would be placed on a table

I mean I want to get the data you select and if there is any way to handle an event to get the selected row automatically

Comment: Would love to help, if I am able to. Would need to see your code so far though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) and [Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html) to accomplish your task :)

Example Code :

```
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard(); 
  // add listner to your tableview selecteditemproperty   
userTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener() {
              // this method will be called whenever user selected row
            @override
             public void chnaged(ObservableValue observale, Object oldValue,Object newValue) {
               UserClass selectedUser = (UserClass)newValue;
             ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                 // make sure you override toString in UserClass
             content.putString(selectedUser.toString()); 
             clipboard.setContent(content); 
            }
            });
```

Comment: It was just what I wanted, thanks for your help, any book you recommend me java fx

Comment: the only book i know for javafx2 http://www.amazon.com/Pro-JavaFX-Definitive-Clients-Technology/dp/1430268727/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353159870&sr=8-1&keywords=javafx+pro

Comment: I am running to similar problems now and I can't thank invariant enough for your answer.

Comment: Can I get the coordinates where the user click in the selected row ,to show something like a popup menu inside the listener?

Answer (score 6):

If i understood you correctly, you want to retrieve the row number of the cell that is currently selected inside a TableView.

To do this, request the SelectionModel of the TableView:

```
    // tv is of type TableView
    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tv.getSelectionModel();
    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
    int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in
```

Comment: I mean I want to get the data you select and if there is any way to handle an event to get the selected row automatically

Answer (score 4):

It's still not clear to me what you are trying to do...

However, getting the selected row:

```
final Countries selectedCountry = tblCountries.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

If there is a need that another pane becomes visible or another window to show just add an eventhandler to the onclicked property or such?

Is it that what you mean?

Comment: he want to copy the data when ever user selected a row in TableView ,so he want to know which event will be called when we selected a row .

Answer (score 3):

```
    tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
        if(tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) 
        {    
           TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableview.getSelectionModel();
           ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
           TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
           Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
           System.out.println("Selected Value" + val);
         }
         }
     });
```

Using this code you can get the selected value from JAVAFX TABLEVIEW Cell.

Thanks..